# Передача массива в свою DLL

Tags: dll, visual-basic, c++, visual-c++

Написал функцию поиска минимума на VC++, завернул её в DLL, теперь пытаюсь передать из VB массив с его размером, валится VB! Как это оформить правильно!?

```
long MinA (long* in_arr,long in_size)
{

    long tmp_min=in_arr[1];
    for (long i=2;i<=in_size;i++)
    {
        if (tmp_min>in_arr[i]) tmp_min=in_arr[i];
    }
    return (tmp_min);
}

Public Declare Function Min Lib "MyDLL.dll" Alias "MinA" (in_arr() As Long, in_size As Long) As Long
```

Comment: @rejie Уважаемый участник, у Вас 0% принятых, пожалуйста, не забывайте принимать (галочка) ответы, если они реально отвечают на Ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В DLL какой тип вызова ф-ции используется? В теории можно сделать какой угодно: stdcall, cdecl, fastcall и пр. Еще нужно согласовать типы данных.
[Толковая ссылка на MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106553)

Comment: Не могу этого сказать, проект на VC++ минимален! Моя функция long MinA (long* in_arr,long in_size), и ещё BOOL APIENTRY DllMain, и файл MyDLL.def с содержанием 
    LIBRARY         "MyDLL"
        DESCRIPTION    'MyDLL - ïðèìåð DLL-áèáëèîòåêè'

    EXPORTS
        MinA    @1

Comment: Для передачи массива какой тип нужно использовать и как!?

Comment: Попробуйте начать с простого: сделайте ф-цию без аргументов, которая будет что-то выводить на экран (в файл) и/или возвращать одно значение. Затем добавьте обычные аргументы. А потом уже указатели. Обратите внимание, что в статье по ссылке указано, что по умолчанию в VB все передается ByRef, т.е. по ссылке. А следовательно, дополнительно это никак не нужно указывать, т.к. ссылка = указатель = адрес переменной.

Comment: Если я передаю обычную переменную и её возвращаю из функции, то всё работает, не работает когда пытаюсь передать массив!

Comment: А если еще раз прочитать статью?

Comment: Ну вроде бы с массивами разобрался! Возник ещё вопрос!
Declare Function IsStartEndPointsTrue Lib "MathDLL.dll" (ByRef pArray As Double, ByVal pSize As Long, ByVal pPointStartOfPeriod As Long, ByVal pPointEndOfPeriod As Long) As Boolean - возвращаю из функции return(false); получаю на vb true!!! В чём дело!?
bool __stdcall IsStartEndPointsTrue (double *pArray, long pSize, long pPointStartOfPeriod, long pPointEndOfPeriod)
{
      return (false);
}

Answer (score 0):

Вы что в хедере писали? Надо было указать:

```
__declspec(dllexport) long minA();
```

чтобы можно было заюзать функцию из dll-ки. И для заметки, массивы в C++ индексируются с 0.

Comment: Я указывал __declspec(dllexport) long minA(); но в этом случае название функции библиотеки представляет собой что то вроде Eghdd4MyDLLdlelk3 (кстати говоря почему?) а когда использую MyDLL.def экспортируемая функция выглядит корректно!(смотрел через Tools Depends)

Comment: да да, сам компилятор там дописывает волшебные символы к названиям функций. поэтому лучше и использовать .def. хотя когда dll к с++проекту прикручиваешь, то всё нормально распознается

Answer (score 0):

long MinA (long* in_arr, long in_size)
{
 long tmp_min=in_arr[0]; 
 for (long i = 1; i < in_size; i++){
     if (tmp_min>in_arr[i])
       tmp_min=in_arr[i];
 } 
 return (tmp_min);
}

Answer (score 0):

не знаю как в VB непосредственно,- но в C# для передачи ссылочных значений нужно включать unsafe контекст...

вот пример определения функции из dll и ее использование в коде C#, если поможет

```
[DllImport("wsock32.dll")]
public static extern int send(SOCKET socket, char* buf, int len, int flag);

static unsafe void Test(string val)
{

fixed (char* value = val)
{
send(socket, value, val.Count * 2, 0)
}

}
```

Comment: P.S unsafe контекст нужно включить и в настройках проекта